# AWS RDS connection from SQLAlchemy responds with error

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect my AWS RDS database instance with SQLAlchemy DBAPI.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from pprint import pprint
# The string form of the URL is dialect[+driver]://user:password@host/dbname[?key=value..]
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@<AWS-RDS-ENDPOINT>:5432/postgres')

session = Session(engine)

# declarative base class
Base = declarative_base()

# an example mapping using the base

# one to many 

# parent class

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    sex = Column(String)
    nationality = Column(Integer)

    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"id: {self.id} name: {self.name} surname: {self.surname} age: {self.age} sex: {self.sex} nationality: {self.nationality}"

# child class

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    sex = Column(String)
    nationality = Column(Integer)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))

    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"id: {self.id} name: {self.name} surname: {self.surname} age: {self.age} sex: {self.sex} nationality: {self.nationality} parent_id: {self.parent_id}"


# create all configuration
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Even though I've set the correct parameters it responds with following error.

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No route to host
        Is the server running on host "postgres.cygbp7ngafcu.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.38.121) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I don't have any knowledge about connections, what could be the problem in this error?

Comment: What do you mean? You have other errors?

Comment: No @Marcin I have other tasks which are more important than this was just a trial :). Thanks for attention

Answer (score 0):

Your RDS is using **private address space** (`172.31.38.121`). This means that you have to [Configuring a Lambda function to access resources in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) where your RDS is located at.

You will also need to modify [security groups of your RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) to allow connections from the lambda function once it is in the VPC.

Alternatively, you would have to make your RDS public and accessible over the internet, but this is **not recommended**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to connect RDS from local.

You need to add your IP in security group to access RDS database from local.

Check this documentation for [Controlling Access With Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)